# iFrame with PHP reCaptcha page enbedded

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have a *Microsoft Expression* web site to which I would like to add a `reCaptcha` page.

I have installed `PHP` and gotten `reCaptcha` working when navigating to the `.php` page with my browser.

The problem however, arises when I try to display the parent page with the `.php` inside of an *iframe*.

I am only getting the `Submit Query` button and not the `reCaptcha` image.

Is there some sort of `<!DOCTYPE>` setting or include that needs to be added to my non-PHP page to allow it to show correctly?

Comment: Are you sure the CSS is also going into the IFrame?

Comment: Yes.  If I can't figure it out I might just migrate to ASP.NET.